# Give index to two equal arrays (in number) and match them on a click event

Tags: jquery, arrays, click, each

I'm building a carousel and I want to match the dots with the pictures on click (and navigate between them). So, in order to do that, I created an array with jQuery of both elemets in this way:

```
var images = $('.images');
var imageslenght = images.length;
console.log(imageslenght); //10
var dot = $('.owl-dot');
var dotlenght = dot.length;
console.log(dotlenght); //10
```

Since they are equals in number I would like to add a click event to them in order to match the position of the array of the image (for example the first image, the second image and so on) with the position of the array of the dot. Something like:

```
$dot.click(function() {
    $dotlenght.each(function( i ) {
        console.log( i );
    });
    $imageslenght.each(function( i ) {
        console.log( i );
    });
});
```

Is there any way to make them match since, for example, when you click the second dot, you're gonna show the second image and so on?

Comment: Are you saying you want to click on a dot and get the correspondingly numbered image back?

Comment: Correct! This is exactly what I want to achieve, I'm going to change the title to my topic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, after loading the page, attach a data tag to every '.owl-dot' element with a unique array index.

```
var i = 0;
$('.owl-dot').each(function() {
   $(this).data('number', i);
   i++;
});
```

Then add a click event handler, to be able to read the clicked dot number.

```
 $('.owl-dot').click(function() {
    var imageNumber = $(this).data('number');
    // now change the image according to the index
    console.log('Array index: ' + imageNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your dot elements are in a wrapper, you can use jQuery's built in index() method to get `.owl-dot`'s index position within that wrapper, e.g.

```
$('.owl-dot').click(function() {
  console.log($('.owl-dot').index($(this)));
});
```

The above code gives you the index which you can then use to retrieve the image, e.g. something like:

`$('.images').eq($('.owl-dot').index($(this)));`

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooByvX), try clicking the letters and check your console.